# Should I make my object properties nullable or use the CLR default values for each type?

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture

I have been trying to figure out the best way to handle default values.  Setting a ID value to 0 makes sense, but if it is a money value or other that is not initially set, when you encounter it later in your code, it is impossible to tell if it has been set or was set to 0.  If a money value is set to null, then you know it has not been set.  Additionally, when dealing with the database, it is simple to know if you need to write a null value to a field vs trying to figure out if it is supposed to be null or not.

What is the accepted way to handle this?

```
Class MyModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public DateTime CreatedDate {get;set;}
    public bool IsActive {get;set;}

    //CLR will automatically set these values
    Public MyModel()
    {
        Id = 0; 
        Title = String.Empty;
        CreatedDate = "1/1/0001";
        IsActive = false;
    }
}
```

vs

```
Class MyModel
{
    public int? Id {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public DateTime? CreatedDate {get;set;}
    public bool? IsActive {get;set;}

    //CLR will automatically set these values
    Public MyModel()
    {
        Id = null; 
        Title = null;
        CreatedDate = null;
        IsActive = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can always mix approaches, depending on your domain.**

```
static class ID
{
    public const int Unassigned = -1;
}

class MyModel
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool? IsAwesome { get; set; }

    Model () 
    {
        // you may use "default" constants...
        Id = ID.Unassigned;
    }

    // you may use optional parameters or overloads
    public MyModel (string title,
        DateTime created = DateTime.Now, // default values may be concrete 
        bool? isAwesome = null)          // or nullable as well
        : this ()                        // and you can chain-call constructors!
    {
        Title = title ?? "<no title>";   // you don't always want null to come through
        CreatedDate = created;     
        IsAwesome = isAwesome;    
    }
}

// Possible usages:
var model = new MyModel ("Hello", new DateTime (2001, 1, 1));
var model = new MyModel ("world", isAwesome: true);
var model = new MyModel (null) {
    IsActive = true
};
```

It may make sense for some attributes to have `null` values, as in “not set”.

In your example, perhaps a model really **doesn't have** an `Id` before it is persisted to the database. If this is the case, and an id-less model **makes sense in terms of business logic**, a nullable `Id` is better than `Id = 0`. However, if your application never works with id-less models, and usually expects `Id` to equal something, it would be crazy to write

```
if (model.Id != null)
```

each time you want to do something with it.

In this case, you should probably go with `Id = 0` by default.
You could also introduce a constant (as I've done above) though I wouldn't recommend it for anything but ids, and only in case they are heavily used by code elsewhere.

**Again, everything depends on the domain.

Your job is to ensure that objects violating business rules can't be created easily.**

Comment: Good answer...before reading it I had already started moving in this direction.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the accepted way to handle this?

Accepted? It depends on the domain.

> If a money value is set to null, then you know it has not been set.

Not necessarily. Imagine I'm using a banking application, and I want to search for a particular transaction, and I get a dialog that looks like this:

```
Enter the fields you know:
Transaction date: 6/26/2011
Payee: Apple
Amount:
```

Now `TransactionSearchParameters.Amount` should be set to null. You can't distinguish this from it not being set.

> Additionally, when dealing with the database, it is simple to know if you need to write a null value to a field vs trying to figure out if it is supposed to be null or not.

You should spend more time modeling your domain properly, and then let an ORM figure out how to get that stuff into the database properly.

Comment: So you recommend NOT setting them unless you need them to be something other than the CLR default OR do you recommend setting them explicitly to some default values?

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea to add here, there is always the [null object pattern](http://www.cs.oberlin.edu/~jwalker/nullObjPattern/) for complex types when appropriate to use.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how are you going to use your code. If the properties are simple types like integers & strings, default values are better, if the properties are objects by themselves, I used nulls, because in C# / Java / PHP, objects references are really object pointers and better to use.

But, if your properties are collections, like lists or maps , its a "better practice" , to create the collection, and leave it empty, instead of null.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Well... the 'best' answer (very opinionated there, but I'm entitled) is when you don't need to differentiate between the two because there is only one possible state, that of being valid:

```
class MyModel
{
    public int Id {get; private set;}
    public string Title {get; private set;}
    public DateTime CreatedDate {get; private set;}
    public bool IsActive {get; private set;}

    Public MyModel(int Id, string Title, DateTime CreatedDate, bool IsActive)
    {
        this.Id = Id; 
        this.Title = Title;
        this.CreatedDate = CreatedDate;
        this.IsActive = IsActive;
    }
}
```

I know this isn't always possible, for instance Query by Example.

Using 'magic numbers' like your "Setting a ID value to 0 makes sense..." is generally avoided.  Once you do this now every piece of code you write must coded to know what these magic number are and what they mean.  This is seldom achieved and full of nasty looking and error prone code.

If you simply **MUST** have the distinction between a field having a value and not, your later example is a little better.  At least here you're value types are explicitly valid or invalid.  However, using Nullable<T> means that you must use a different means to determine if a class, string, or other reference type is invalid.

IMO, You are better off with the following, although it becomes very verbose as you will see.

```
class MyModel
{
    private int _id;
    public bool HasId { get; set; }
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            if (!HasId) throw new System.InvalidOperationException();
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            HasId = true;
            _id = value;
        }
    }

    private string _title;
    public bool HasTitle { get; set; }
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            if (!HasTitle) throw new System.InvalidOperationException();
            return _title;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == null) throw new System.ArgumentNullException("Title");
            HasTitle = true;
            _title = value;
        }
    }

    private DateTime _createdDate;
    public bool HasCreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate
    {
        get
        {
            if (!HasCreatedDate) throw new System.InvalidOperationException();
            return _createdDate;
        }
        set
        {
            HasCreatedDate = true;
            _createdDate = value;
        }
    }

    private bool _isActive;
    public bool HasIsActive { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get
        {
            if (!HasIsActive) throw new System.InvalidOperationException();
            return _isActive;
        }
        set
        {
            HasIsActive = true;
            _isActive = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, If you are going this route a code generator will serve you well.

Comment: I want to vote +1 for the first part as much as to vote -1 for the second.

Comment: To expand, the second part is a typical sample of the problem nullable types *solved* with their neat syntax. My head hurts when I think something as simple as `public bool? IsActive { get; set; }` gets **15 times** more lines than it deserves. Yes—the trick wouldn't work with strings but there's `null` there that fits the purpose quite fine.

Comment: @gaearon agreed in the later case, it is verbose as I warned, and for what it's worth I've never hand-written code that way.  I have however done that in code generators.  Using 'null' is still a 'magic' value and must be checked by the consumer or asserted by the 'getter/setter' methods.  If you assert for non-null values in the getter/setter then your back to most every line of code in the later example. Moreover you still need to expose the boolean "HasWhatever" to see if the value was supplied, so in the end using 'null' and Nullable<T> gains you nothing in terms of LoC.

Comment: (cont'd)  I despise null and every property that can return it.  It should be avoided or prevented.  If nothing else use a TryGetValue(...) pattern rather than returning null.  It at least keeps the logic internal and properties are exposed as their type (int) instead of nullable types (int?).

Comment: I have decided to stick with the default values for *most* cases and force nulls when needed.  Your first example is good, but there are certain cases when I may need to partially hydrate a object and to me, an object can only really be invalid if it fails the business rules when you try to do something that requires the rules. eg - a new instance of a object may not have a Id until it is saved to the database.